# Lua Alien - Pointer Arithmetic and Dereferencing

Tags: pointers, lua, lua-alien

My goal is to call Windows' [GetModuleInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get a [MODULEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct back.  This is all working fine.  The problem comes as a result of me wanting to do pointer arithmetic and dereferences on the `LPVOID lpBaseOfDll` which is part of the `MODULEINFO`.

Here is my code to call the function in Lua:

```
require "luarocks.require"
require "alien"

sizeofMODULEINFO = 12   --Gotten from sizeof(MODULEINFO) from Visual Studio

MODULEINFO = alien.defstruct{
    {"lpBaseOfDll", "pointer"};    --Does this need to be a buffer? If so, how?
    {"SizeOfImage", "ulong"};
    {"EntryPoint", "pointer"};
}

local GetModuleInformation = alien.Kernel32.K32GetModuleInformation
GetModuleInformation:types{ret = "int", abi = "stdcall", "long", "pointer", "pointer", "ulong"}

local GetModuleHandle = alien.Kernel32.GetModuleHandleA
GetModuleHandle:types{ret = "pointer", abi = "stdcall", "pointer"}

local GetCurrentProcess = alien.Kernel32.GetCurrentProcess
GetCurrentProcess:types{ret = "long", abi = "stdcall"}

local mod = MODULEINFO:new() --Create struct (needs buffer?)

local currentProcess = GetCurrentProcess()
local moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle("myModule.dll")
local success = GetModuleInformation(currentProcess, moduleHandle, mod(), sizeofMODULEINFO)

if success == 0 then  --If there is an error, exit
    return 0
end

local dataPtr = mod.lpBaseOfDll

--Now how do I do pointer arithmetic and/or dereference "dataPtr"?
```

At this point, `mod.SizeOfImage` seems to be giving me the correct values that I am expecting, so I know the functions are being called and the struct is being populated.  However, I cannot seem to do pointer arithmetic on `mod.lpBaseOfDll` because it is a `UserData`.

The only information in the [Alien Documentation](http://alien.luaforge.net/) that may address what I'm trying to do are these:

1. Pointer Unpacking

> Alien also provides three convenience functions that let you
>   dereference a pointer and convert the value to a Lua type:
>
> alien.tostring takes a userdata (usually returned from a function that has a pointer return value), casts it to char*, and returns a Lua
>   string. You can supply an optional size argument (if you don’t Alien
>   calls strlen on the buffer first).
>
> alien.toint takes a userdata, casts it to int*, dereferences it and returns it as a number. If you pass it a number it assumes the
>   userdata is an array with this number of elements.
>
> alien.toshort, alien.tolong, alien.tofloat, and alien.todouble are like alien.toint, but works with with the respective typecasts.
>   Unsigned versions are also available.

My issue with those, is I would need to go byte-by-byte, and there is no `alien.tochar` function.  Also, and more importantly, this still doesn't solve the problem of me being able to get elements outside of the base address.

2. Buffers

> After making a buffer you can pass it in place of any argument of
>   string or pointer type.
>
> ...
>
> You can also pass a buffer or other userdata to the new method of your
>   struct type, and in this case this will be the backing store of the
>   struct instance you are creating. This is useful for unpacking a
>   foreign struct that a C function returned.

These seem to suggest I can use an `alien.buffer` as the argument of `MODULEINFO`'s `LPVOID lpBaseOfDll`.  And buffers are described as byte arrays, which can be indexed using this notation:  `buf[1]`, `buf[2]`, etc.  Additionally, buffers go by bytes, so this would ideally solve all problems. (If I am understanding this correctly).

Unfortunately, I can not find any examples of this anywhere (not in the docs, stackoverflow, Google, etc), so I am have no idea how to do this.  I've tried a few variations of syntax, but nearly every one gives a runtime error (others simply does not work as expected).

Any insight on how I might be able to go byte-by-byte (C char-by-char) across the `mod.lpBaseOfDll` through dereferences and pointer arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to go byte-by-byte, and there is no alien.tochar function.

Sounds like `alien.tostring` has you covered:

> alien.tostring takes a userdata (usually returned from a function that has a pointer return value), casts it to char*, and returns a Lua string. You can supply an optional size argument (if you don’t Alien calls strlen on the buffer first).

Lua strings can contain arbitrary byte values, including 0 (i.e. they aren't null-terminated like C strings), so as long as you pass a size argument to `alien.tostring` you can get back data as a byte buffer, aka Lua string, and do whatever you please with the bytes.

It sounds like you *can't* tell it to start at an arbitrary offset from the given pointer address. The easiest way to tell for sure, if the documentation doesn't tell you, is to look at the source. It would probably be trivial to add an offset parameter.